# HP Color Laserjet 2600n - "Printer is not responding"

Tags: networking, printing, hp-printer

I've been trying to install an HP Color Laserjet 2600n printer for use over a network connection from my Linux desktop, but I can't get it working and I'm not sure what else to try.

I am using Parabola, which is a libre variant of Arch. I have installed the '[foo2hp](http://foo2hp.rkkda.com/)' driver, which apparently supports this printer model. In CUPS, if I go to 'add new printer', it seems to discover it fine over the network. I select the driver from the model list, which includes this model. All of that seems to work fine, and I get a page for the new printer that says 'Idle, Accepting Jobs, Not Shared'. However, if I try to print a test page or send a print job to it, I get an error message saying 'The Printer is not Responding'.

The printer works fine with my wife's Apple Powerbook, so I know it works and it is accepting jobs over the network. If I do `$ avahi-browse --all --ignore-local --resolve --terminate`, I get the following lines relating to the HP printer:

```
= wlp3s0 IPv4 HP Color LaserJet 2600n                       PDL Printer          local
   hostname = [NPIC0ED3E.local]
   address = [169.254.68.128]
   port = [9100]
   txt = ["Binary=T" "Transparent=T" "usb_MDL=HP Color LaserJet 2600n" "usb_MFG=Hewlett-Packard" "adminurl=http://169.254.68.128" "priority=30" "product=(Hewlett-Packard HP Color LaserJet 2600n)" "ty=HP Color LaserJet 2600n" "pdl=application/vnd.zeno-zjs,application/vnd.cups-raster" "qtotal=1" "txtvers=1"]
= wlp3s0 IPv4 HP Color LaserJet 2600n                       Web Site             local
   hostname = [NPIC0ED3E.local]
   address = [169.254.68.128]
   port = [80]
   txt = []
```

This implies there is a web page I should be able to use to manage the printer. However, if I type `169.254.68.128` into my web browser, nothing happens and it eventually times out. The printer also doesn't seem to respond to ping requests from my desktop. So, it seems that something is not right with the connection (although it seems to respond to the Powerbook fine, as mentioned earlier)?

Any ideas what the issue might be? I've spent several hours already trying to get this thing running and I'm out of ideas.

**Update:**

I have confirmed that the printer responds to pings from the Powerbook and allows access to the management web page, but not from my desktop or laptop, which are both running Parabola Linux.

Comment: That IP address seems dubious, 169.254... is a [link local address](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address). If the printer had used a dhcp it should have something different.  How are you wired into it? Is it plugged into your router?

Comment: @PhilipCouling yes, it is plugged into the router via an ethernet cable. I haven't done anything special with the IP setup. I typed that IP into the browser on the powerbook and it brings up the printer management page. So, the IP seems correct, as far as I can tell.

Comment: "correct" is a relative term. I think it's clear that the printer thinks that is its IP but I don't think it *should* be its IP address.  It indicates the printer is not configuring with DHCP (as most things should).  I don't think Linux will automatically talk to link-local IPv4 addresses.  You have two options: try to get linux to talk to an ipv4 link-local address.  Try to configure your printer "correctly" so that it get's its IP address from your router's DHCP server.

Comment: This might help if you don't want to re-configure your printer. https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Link-local_address/Linux#Obtain_an_IPv4_link-local_address

Comment: @PhilipCouling ok thanks, this is helpful information. I will look into configuring the printer IP with DHCP and see if that helps.

Comment: @PhilipCouling the printer seemed to already be set to use DHCP, but for some reason it had been assigned that link local IP address. So, I reset the IP configuration and it was reassigned a more typical 192.168 address and it now it is working from Linux. Thanks very much for your help. If you feel like posting an answer, I'll be happy to accept. Otherwise, I'll post one myself to close out the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suspicious thing here is that the printer's IP address  is a [link-local IPv4 address](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) (169.254.x.x).  Linux does have support for using these but isn't commonly configured to use them by default.

It means that your router didn't assign this IP.  DHCP servers (almost) never assign a link-local IP and will usually by default assign a [private network IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) (`10.x.x.x`, `172.16.x.x` to `172.32.x.x`, or `192.168.x.x`).

The most likely situation is that your linux machine only has a Private Network IP and so cannot talk to the link-local address.  There is some information on setting up a link-local address on Linux if you prefer, here: https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Link-local_address/Linux#Obtain_an_IPv4_link-local_address

However the easier thing to do is to try to re-configure your printer settings to assign an IP from your network's DHCP Server.  You should find this is generally more compatible with other machines on your network.  Settings on how to do this will vary from printer to printer.